# QGIS export layer relations from one project to another

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, layers, qml, relation

I have a `.qgz` project with a spatial layer and two non-spatial layers, primarily created for data collection. All the three layers are saved in a single `.gpkg` file and the non-spatial layers are related to the spatial layer by `Relations` created in `Project Properties` and it works fine.

Now, I want to use these layers with their relations and Form layout in another master project. For this, I tried exporting the layer style as `.qml` file (including relations) and then loaded the data and the style file in the master project. While I am able to see the desired form layout, the relations are not appearing. I know I can create relations again in the new project but I am looking for a seamless way to get the job done.

Am I missing something here? Or does it not work this way?

*Qgis 3.28 & Windows 11*

Comment: I didn't try it but recent (don't remember witch version) QGIS let you create relation directly in your geopackage. Since 3.28 relation should be automatically used if present in your GPKG (https://qgis.org/zh-Hans/site/forusers/visualchangelog328/index.html#id46 ; https://qgis.org/zh-Hans/site/forusers/visualchangelog328/index.html#id52)

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using version 3.28 currently. The method you have mentioned does the packaging of related layers in addition to to those selected for packaging. I have already tried that and it didn't serve my purpose.

Comment: While the packaging is indeed a new feature of 3.28 there is two other new feature relevant to your case "Feature: Automatically add related tables when adding layers from GDAL datasets with embedded relationship information" and "Feature: Implement relationship discovery for OGR layers, and show relationships in browser". Try to create the relation in the data source provider (select your gpkg, right click and select create new relationship)

Comment: Relationship discovery apparently works with the relations defined by FOREIGN KEY only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all possible ways, I have found one work around for this.

The `Relations` created within a `QGIS` project from `Project Properties` is saved in the `.qgz` file and is not embedded with the `.gpkg`. However, the layer style `.qml` file does contain some partial information, which is not useful anyways. You will see a blank relation in the `Form Layout`.

The solution here is to embed the project file with the relations inside the master project file using `Layer > Embed Layers and Groups`. By this way, all `Relations`, `Form Layouts` and `Styles` are embedded in the master project. However, you cannot access layer properties of embedded layers from the master project. For that you need to duplicate the layers within the master project or change properties within the original project file.

PS: You have to make sure the directories of both projects are portable together while maintaining the relative paths.